# Laravel Lumen queues job fails and throws method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm working on a Laravel Lumen project. My Lumen project is connected to my database where another Laravel project connects, I'm splitting the load by using Lumen here.

I've created a Job in Lumen and nested this in a directory called Reports inside my Jobs folder, but when running `queue:work --queue=reports` I'm getting this error:

> method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Jobs\Reports\ConsolidateAverageConversions" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition

What am I missing in my Job?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Reports;

use App\Traits\Reports;
use App\Traits\Graphs;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ConsolidateAverageConversions extends Job
{
    use Reports, Graphs;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public $queue = 'reports';

    /**
     * Chosen report
     */
    public $report;

    /**
     * Chosen journey
     */
    public $journey;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($report, $journey)
    {
        $this->report = $report;
        $this->journey = $journey;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $from = Carbon::now()->subMonths(1)->startOfDay();
        $to = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();

        // the raw data
        $conversions = $this->getAverageDailyConversionRate($from, $to, $this->journey);
        
        // generate a chart
        $graph = $this->createChart($conversions, [
            'chart_name' => 'average_conversions',
            'label' => 'date',
            'metric' => 'conversion_rate'
        ]);

        // create the report in our db
        $this->createReport([
            'charts' => $graph,
            'report' => $conversions
        ], $this->report);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you restart the queue worker? Also make sure the parameters you are passing to the job can be serialized (not everything can)

Comment: `$report` passed into my constructor is a string, as is my `$journey` variable too. So surely Laravel Lumen can serialize these? I'm working locally in my development environment so have restarted my queue several times, no luck.